# Vega lite top and bottom 10

Tags: vega-lite

I was wondering if it is possible to display both the top and bottom 10 objects (quantitative) next to each other in vega lite.

I know how to get them individually but not both:

```
 "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "Days_to_maturity", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank <= 10"}
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
  "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "Days_to_maturity", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "rank", "as": "total"}]}
    {"filter": "(datum.rank <= 10) || (datum.rank > datum.total - 10)"}
  ],
```

Note that the `rank` aggregate will give equal values the same rank, so this may not display exactly 10 at each end if there are duplicate values in your data. If you want to just display the first and last 10 rows regardless of duplicates, you can change to a `count` window with `ignorePeers`:

```
  "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "count", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "Days_to_maturity", "order": "descending"}],
      "ignorePeers": true
    },
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "rank", "as": "total"}]},
    {"filter": "(datum.rank <= 10) || (datum.rank > datum.total - 10)"}
  ],
```

You can find more details on window transform options in the [Window Transform docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html).

Comment: Thanks, just wondering, is there a way to separate them into two graphs? one with the top and the other with the bottom.

Comment: Sure, you could [concatenate](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/concat.html) two views of the data, one which filters the top 10 and one which filters the bottom 10.

Comment: So you can do a hconcat or vconcat separately with different filter? How would that look like? thanks. I keep looking online but vega lite gives 0 examples.

Comment: This is a different topic than the original question and requires more space than is available in a comment thread. I'd suggest opening a new question.